# SQLite select where column does not contain certain data

Tags: sql, sqlite, contain

ok so I have a table that looks something like this...(using pipe symbol to separate columns)

```
example1 url|0
example2 url|0
example3 url|1
example4 url|1,2
example5 url|1,3,6
```

What I am trying to do is to select all rows where column 2 does NOT contain a 1.

I cannot use != because if you look all but one of those would return data because the last 2 rows don't equal 1. I tried scouring SQLite documentation for how to go about writing the statement, but I can't find it. This is what I have so far.

```
select * from table_name where table_column_name[something needed here]'1';
```

Comment: Are they strings?  It certainly looks like they are.

Answer (score 7):

Give that "1,2,3" et al are strings, you probably need the LIKE keyword.

```
 select * from table_name where table_column_name NOT LIKE '%1%'
```

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly. What do the percentage signs do?

Comment: This works ONLY for numbers from 0 to 9. This query will ignore "2,3,11" though it shouldn't.

Comment: How to avoid this. Change the format of the second column. For example, from "1,2,4" to "(1)(2)(4)". And change the query condition to "NOT LIKE "%(1)%".

Comment: The percentage signs are wildcards.  They indicate that the `LIKE` keyword should ignore everything before and after the 1.

Comment: Try runnning this query: "SELECT '4,5,11' NOT LIKE '%1%'". It will return 0 which is not that OP expected.

Comment: @chuck.p.lee I agree.  The other answer is a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

For matching a list item separated by `,`, use:

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE `,`||column||`,` NOT LIKE '%,1,%';
```

this will match entire item (ie, only `1`, not `11`, ...), whether it is at list beginning, middle or end.